# Different referer value between IE and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, http, http-headers

I have one page with following code:

```
<form method="post" action="/licensefile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" summary="" style="width:100%;">
<tbody><tr><td style="width:70%;"><input type="file" name="file" style="width:100%;"></td><td style="width:20%;">
<input type="submit" value="Install License File"></td></tr></tbody></table></form>
```

Now test it under `IE` and `Chrome`, however, I get the different `Referer` value in HTTP header. Why?

IE:

```
POST http://172.16.63.60:15060/licensefile HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, **
Referer: http://172.16.63.60:15060/body.html?menu=25
```

Chrome:

```
POST http://172.16.63.60:15060/licensefile HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.63.60:15060
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,**;q=0.8
Origin: http://172.16.63.60:15060
Referer: http://172.16.63.60:15060/licensefile
```